# Web Content Accessibility - Name

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag2.0

I'm just starting to learn about Web Content Accessibility and I was reading [this document](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/text-equiv-all.html) regarding **non-text contents**.

According to it:

> For non-text content that is a control or accepts user input, such as
>   images used as submit buttons, image maps or complex animations, a
>   name is provided to describe the purpose of the non-text content so
>   that the person at least knows what the non-text content is and why it
>   is there.

So I double checked if what was meant here as `name` is the same as the HTML name attribute and found out that it isn't.

Near the bottom of the document here's what the definition of `name` is:

#### name

> text by which software can identify a component within Web content to
>   the user
>
> Note 1: The name may be hidden and only exposed by assistive
>   technology, whereas a label is presented to all users. In many (but
>   not all) cases, the label and the name are the same.
>
> Note 2: This is unrelated to the name attribute in HTML.

So my question is how do I incorporate this `name` in my website if it's not the HTML attribute?

Comment: As you quote a way to give a name (→ with a label), do you ask about cases where a label is not appropriate? What’s your case?

Comment: Accessible Name Calculation is the document you are looking for: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-aapi-20110414/ 
Support matrix: https://labs.ssbbartgroup.com/index.php/Accessible_Name_Link_Test

Comment: @unor I guess the reason why I asked this question is because I'm confused as to what this `name` is. While reading the document I thought it was referring to the `name` attribute of an input but it turns out I understood the document incorrectly. I was just wondering what this `name` is so that I would know how to build my pages. An answer below says that **labels**, **text inside buttons**, and **alt attributes** are the names. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the control you are using. Some examples:

- Input controls, textarea:

  Use the `label` element with the `for` attribute, matching the `id` attribute of the element.

  ```html
  <label for="input1">My label</label><input type="text" id="input1" />
  ```
- Buttons

  If you use the `button` element include the description inside the content

  ```html
  <button>My label</button>
  ```

  For `input[type=submit]`, you can use the `value` attribute:

  ```html
  <input type="submit" value="My label" />
  ```
- If you want to describe an image, use the `alt` attribute

  Ex:

  ```html
  <img src="..." alt="My label" />
  ```

Comment: This sounds like the explanation I needed to understand the document properly - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See my answer on [If an HTML element has role="button" should it also have the attribute "name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477954/if-an-html-element-has-role-button-should-it-also-have-the-attribute-name/38490841#38490841).  Another person was asking about the "name" of an object and I clarified that the name of an object is not the name= property (that property is used for javascript) but rather is the label of the object that assistive technology will surface to the user.  More details in my post.

Comment: Yup thanks. Basically the same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The "name" attribute you mean is an attribute of the tag you are using in the web page. Example: [Tag Button](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) you can specify the name of the tag to facilitate user. Note 2 is telling you that HTML tag is unrelated to this attribute.

Comment: So you mean just the `<button>` is enough?

Comment: You can use the attribute name like this: <button name="name_of_button" ></button>. This is useful to get more informations about the button in the page, for accessibility.

Comment: But doesn't the document express that it is not referring to the HTML attribute called `name`?